# Karma (singleRun:false) - stop chrome exiting on thrown errors

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have singleRun set to false, so I can use the debugger and prevent chrome closing on completion

However when a test case throws an error it kills the browser (chrome). Is there a way to force the browser to remain open despite this?

Comment: I don't think that's how karma-chrome-launcher is supposed to behave.  By error do you mean 'bad test' or 'failed test'?  It also wouldn't be a bad idea to post your `karma.conf.js` file.